# What is the purpose of $eq

Tags: mongodb

I noticed a new `$eq` operator released with `MongoDB 3.0` and I don't understand the purpose of it. For instance these two queries are exactly the same:

```
db.users.find({age:21})
```

and

```
db.users.find({age:{$eq:21}})
```

Does anyone know why this was necessary?

Comment: @user2864740 it is valid, this docs mentions that such queries (`{age:21}` and `{age:{$eq:21}}`) are equal: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/

Comment: @Messa How confusing, I had the wrong page open :(

Comment: Yes, it looks confusing :) Maybe `$eq` (in "normal" queries) is to distinguish between `null` and absent key. But I cannot test it now.

Comment: I think `db.users.find({age:{$eq:null}})` would be the same as `db.users.find({age:null})`

Comment: I just did a test and they both run at exactly the same speed.

Comment: `$eq` can be used for projection in an aggregate query: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/

Comment: `$eq` treats the value as literal, so you can use it to prevent injection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that you'd have to handle equality differently from comparison when you had some kind of query builder, so it's

```
{ a : { $gt : 3 } }
{ a : { $lt : 3 } }
```

but

```
{ a : 3 }
```

for equality, which looks completely different. The same applies for composition of `$not`, as JohnnyHK already pointed out. Also, comparing with `$eq` saves you from having to `$`-escape user provided strings. Therefore, people [asked for alternatives that are syntactically closer](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1367) and it was implemented. The Jira ticket contains a longer discussion which mentions all these points.

The clearer syntax of an `$eq` operator might also make sense in the aggregation framework to compare two fields, should [such a feature](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7623) be implemented.

Also, the feature has apparently been around since 2.5, was [added to the documentation relatively late](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-4346).

Answer (score 6):

One specific application I can see for `$eq` is with cases like the [`$not`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#op._S_not) operator which *requires* that its value is an `operator-expression`.

This allows you to construct a query like:

```js
db.zips.find({state: {$not: {$eq: 'NY'}}})
```

Before, the closest you could get to this semantically was:

```js
db.zips.find({state: {$not: {$regex: /^NY$/}}})
```

I realize there are other ways to represent the *functionality* of that query, but if you need to use the `$not` operator there for other reasons, this would now allow it.

Comment: Before that you could use `$ne` (but you probably know this) :)

Comment: It's weird, though. I thought this operator existed for a long time.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It has always been there. The only thing that is new is documentation. So all the replies are quite amusing.

Answer (score 2):

In filter part of an aggregation query if you need to check if some field is equal to a value you can not use assign syntax:

```
db.sales.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         items: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$items",
               as: "item",
               cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.price", 100 ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```